# 60s-70s sci-fi show/episode about time slow-down

Tags: story-identification, tv

Sort of like *The Outer Limits*' "The Premonition", this was a story that included a time-slow-down mechanism set on a military base (at least partially).  I was sure it was *The Outer Limits* but I've looked at all episodes and it must be some other show.  Very much that kind of production and timeframe.  1960s - possibly early 70s.

It appeared to a small group of people that time for the rest of the world was frozen but actually was just moving very slowly.  But it turned out that it was the small group of people that were moving at a hyperspeed - so fast that they were invisible to the rest of the world.  The show had perspectives from both sides.  The only clue to the rest of the world was a kind of buzzing sound they would hear when the smaller/faster group or individual was near.

I don't remember the story, though it must have been an episode of some sci-fi show.  Apologies for being vague but this was the 60's, I was young, etc. but these memories are very specific.

Comment: I remember this. I thought it was a movie. Maybe early 60s. I don’t remember the whole story but the people looked to be frozen in time but when they looked at them close, they were just moving incredibly slow. They were trying to get back to their own time. I have a kids memory of this. Don’t remember the name of it.

Comment: @Suzie, that is probably the film _The Time Travelers_,  or its remake _Journey to the Center of Time_. See my post below for links.

Answer (score 12):

I think it's probably an episode of *Star Trek* (TOS) - ["Wink Of An Eye"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wink_of_an_Eye) (1968).

> "Wink of an Eye" is the eleventh episode of the third season of the American science fiction television series *Star Trek*. [...]
>
> In the episode, normally invisible time-accelerated aliens take over the *Enterprise* and attempt to abduct the crew for use as breeding stock. [...]
>
> In answer to a distress call, the Federation starship *Enterprise* arrives at the planet Scalos. Captain Kirk beams down with a landing party to a city with no evidence of life, except for an intermittent insect-like buzzing.

If not, then an alternative possibility is the film [*The Time Travelers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Travelers_(1964_film)) (1964) or its remake [*Journey To The Center of Time*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_to_the_Center_of_Time) (1967).  At the end of the film(s) the time travelers meet their earlier selves. Except they are somehow accelerated, so their earlier selves are moving as slowly as the hands of a clock.

Comment: When on the enterprise, the aliens sound like mosquitoes buzzing.